# Why Doesn't This Integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{x^2} \ dx$ Work?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, triangles

I am trying to solve this integral, which is incorrect compared to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt%28x%5E2-9%29%2Fx%5E3+dx). Why doesn't my method work?

> Find $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{x^2} \ dx$
>
> ---
>
> Side work:
>
> [image]
>
> $\sin{\theta} = \frac{3}{x}$
>
> $x = \frac{3}{\sin{\theta}} = 3 \csc{\theta}$
>
> $dx = -3 \csc{\theta}\cot{\theta} \ d\theta$
>
> ---
>
> $-\int \frac{\sqrt{9\csc^2{\theta} - 9}}{27 \csc^3{\theta}} \cdot 3 \csc{\theta}\tan{\theta} \ d\theta$
>
> $-\int \frac{3 \cdot \sqrt{\csc^2{\theta} - 1}}{27 \csc^3{\theta}} \cdot 3 \csc{\theta}\cot{\theta} \ d\theta$
>
> $-\int \frac{\cot{\theta}\csc{\theta}\cot{\theta}}{3 \csc^3{\theta}} \ d\theta$
>
> $-\frac{1}{3} \int \cos^2{\theta} \ d\theta$
>
> $-\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \cos{\left(2\theta\right)}\right) \ d\theta$
>
> $-\frac{1}{6} \int 1 + \cos{\left(2\theta\right)} \ d\theta$
>
> $-\frac{1}{6} \int \ d\theta + \frac{1}{6} \int \cos{\left(2\theta\right)} \ d\theta$
>
> ---
>
> Sidework:
>
> $u = 2\theta$
>
> $du = 2 \ d\theta$
>
> ---
>
> $-\frac{1}{6} \int \ d\theta + \frac{1}{3} \int \cos{u} \ du$
>
> $-\frac{\theta}{6} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sin{u} + C$
>
> $-\frac{\theta}{6} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sin{2\theta} + C$
>
> ---
>
> Sidework:
>
> $\sin{\left(2\theta\right)} = 2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}$
>
> $\sin{\theta} = \frac{3}{x}$
>
> $\cos{\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{x}$
>
> $\theta = \sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)}$
>
> ---
>
> $-\frac{\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)}}{6} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{x} + C$
>
> $-\frac{\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)}}{6} + \frac{2\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}{x^2} + C$

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $\csc \theta$ is not $\csc \theta \tan \theta$ it is $-\csc \theta \cot \theta$.

After your edit:

Try writing $\sin^{-1} (3/x)$ in the form of $\tan^{-1}$.

Also you have the integral of $\cos 2\theta$ wrong.

Comment: (cold chills) ... yes, your right, let me try re-evaluating

Comment: Fixed the above work. Interestingly, it only resulted in a few sign changes. Any further ideas?

Comment: @spryno724: Try writing $\sin^{-1} (3/x)$ in the form of $\tan^{-1}$... Also you have the integral of $\cos 2\theta$ wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**Added:** It has been pointed out that there may be some ambiguity about the integral the OP is trying to find.  The introduction has an $x^2$ at the bottom, but in the solution the OP seems to be using $x^3$. That is much easier.  The substitution $x=3\sec\theta$ transforms the integrand into a constant times $\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}$, which is just $\sin^2\theta$.

**Original post:** If we are going to use a trigonometric substitution, I would let $x=3\sec\theta$. (Secant is a bit more familiar than cosecant. You are therefore less likely to differentiate $\sec\theta$ incorrectly; incorrect differentiation of $\csc\theta$ spoiled our integration.)

Then $dx=3\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$. Plug in. From now on, I will forget about constants. So everything is a little wrong, but only by a constant factor.

On top we get $(\tan\theta)(\sec\theta\tan\theta)$. On the bottom we get $\sec^2\theta$. 
So we are interested in 
$$\frac{\tan^2\theta\sec\theta}{\sec^2\theta}.$$
Put everything in terms of sines and cosines. We get $\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta}$.

There is a trick that one can use when there is an odd power of sine or cosine. In this case, multiply top and bottom by $\cos\theta$, and replace the $\cos^2\theta$ now at the bottom by $1-\sin^2\theta$.
We have arrived at 
$$\int \frac{\cos\theta \,\sin^2\theta}{1-\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta.$$
Make the substitution $u=\sin\theta$.
We arrive at
$$\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2}\,du.$$
The integrand is a *rational function*. It can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{1}{1-u^2}-1.$$
But (partial fractions) we find that $\dfrac{1}{1-u^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+u}+\dfrac{1}{1-u}\right)$.

**Remark:** As usual, there are many other approaches. For example, we can change $\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec\theta}$ to $\frac{\sec^2\theta-1}{\sec\theta}$, and then to $\sec\theta -\cos\theta$.  If we happen to know the integral of $\sec\theta$, we are essentially finished.  More strikingly, if we guess somehow that $F(x)$ is an antiderivative, then the magic substitution $u=F(x)$ solves the problem.

Comment: He needs $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x^3}dx$ not $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x^2}dx$, though he put the latter one in the first paragraph (he solves with the cube).

Answer (score 0):

Let  $I  = \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 – 9}}{x^2}$

Easiest is a hyperbolic substitution:

Put  $x = 3\cosh{u}, u \le 0$, so $dx = 3\sinh(u)du$

Then \begin{align}
I &=\int\frac{3\sinh(u^2)}{9 \cosh^2(u)}du\\\\
&= \int\tanh^2(u)du\\\\
&= \int\left(1–\mathrm{sech}^2(u)\right)du\\\\
&= u–\tanh(u)+c\\\\
&= u-\frac{3\sinh(u)}{3\cosh(u)}+c\\\\
&= \cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x^2–9}}{x}+c\\
\end{align}